# Company Data formatting

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have the following dataset:

| EID | CLEAN_NAME | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A111 | ABC | 2003-11-01 | 2005-12-31 |
| A111 | DEF | 2005-12-01 | 2007-08-31 |
| A111 | GHI | 2007-09-01 | 2012-01-31 |
| A111 | GHI | 2012-01-01 | 2013-05-31 |
| A111 | JKL | 2013-06-01 | 2015-03-31 |
| A111 | MNO | 2015-04-01 | 2016-04-30 |
| A111 | GHI | 2016-04-18 | 2017-11-07 |
| A111 | GHI | 2017-11-01 | NaT |

Following is the expected outcome:

| EID | CLEAN_NAME | Start_Date | End_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A111 | ABC | 2003-11-01 | 2005-12-31 |
| A111 | DEF | 2005-12-01 | 2007-08-31 |
| A111 | GHI | 2007-09-01 | 2013-05-31 |
| A111 | JKL | 2013-06-01 | 2015-03-31 |
| A111 | MNO | 2015-04-01 | 2016-04-30 |
| A111 | GHI | 2016-04-18 |  |

What I am trying to do here is for company aggregating the company data with respect to their EID and CLEAN_NAME and taking minimum of Start_Date and maximum of End_Date. If I do simple aggregation for GHI company minimum of Start_Date will come as 2007-09-01 and maximum of End_Date will come as 2017-11-07 which is incorrect.

Basically I want to separate GHI company as they are two different data. I understand I may have to use nested for loops for EID, CLEAN_NAME and Start_Date and End_Date to compare the data between each row but I can't seem to get it to work as I am unable to understand the usage and logic to implement it in the loop. Here is what I started with(which is not much to go on but stil...):

```
   for i in df['EID']:
        for j in df['CLEAN_NAME']:
             if j == j-1
        for k in df['Start_Date']:
             print(df['EID'])
```

This is just a sample to check how the nested for loop works(which it didn't because I got an error in line if j == j-1). I am new to python and still trying to figure out how things work.

Also note the dataset is already sorted with respect to EID, Start_date, End_date and CLEAN_NAME. So basically I have to merge consecutive duplicate rows with min of Start_date and max of End_date and the last company with min of Start_date and End_date as NULL since it indicates that the employee is currently working in this company..

Any leads would be appreciated thanks.!

Comment: EID is going to be like this, or is it going to be unique for everything ? And `j==j-1` is never going to be true in this world!.

Comment: It's going to be unique for the entire set....I mean I have a list of almost hundreds of EIDs with their respective company data. In this case I posted the data for only one EID. I will have multiple EIDs in the dataset. So here I have data for A111 then I will have data for B111, C111 and so on...

Comment: Yes, but as you see, `GHI` has 4 rows with same EID, but you want to aggregate them as 2 different companies, Is that right ?

Comment: yupp yupp...correct.! I want it for the same EID.

Comment: If you are aggregating, all EID-CLEAN_NAME unique combinations, then its straight forward, and you don't need any loops.

Comment: Yes....but I won't be able to split GHI company in two different rows as given in the expected output....The output that I will get will be only 1 row for GHI company where Start_Date will be 2007-09-01 and End_Date will be 2017-11-07. I am sorry for the earlier comment.....both records with GHI company belong to same company which is GHI....they are not 2 different companies. I apologize for not being clear earlier.

Comment: So its more like merging consecutive duplicate rows with max and min dates?

Comment: aah yes correct...the dataset is already sorted with respect to eid, start date, end date and clean_name so yes I have to merge consecutive duplicate rows with min of start date and max of end date and the last company with min of start date and end date as NULL since it indicates that the employee is currently working in this company...

Comment: Would be good, if you update the question with these comment insights.

Comment: done....Is it a bit better to understand now.? thank for suggesting this.! I want to make the question as better as possible.!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, here is one solution, which does not make use of loops.

```
df['groups'] = (df['CLEAN_NAME'].ne(df['CLEAN_NAME'].shift())).cumsum()
df = df.groupby(["groups"]).agg({"EID": "first", "CLEAN_NAME": "first", "Start_Date": min, "End_Date": max}).reset_index()
print(df[["EID", "CLEAN_NAME", "Start_Date", "End_Date"]])
```

In this approach, we created groups of rows which has the same CLEAN_NAME, occurring consecutively. And then, aggregate the df, based on the group.

The output looks like this

```
    EID CLEAN_NAME  Start_Date    End_Date
0  A111        ABC  2003-11-01  2005-12-31
1  A111        DEF  2005-12-01  2007-08-31
2  A111        GHI  2007-09-01  2013-05-31
3  A111        JKL  2013-06-01  2015-03-31
4  A111        MNO  2015-04-01  2016-04-30
5  A111        GHI  2016-04-18         NaT
```

Does this work for you ?

Comment: This works....expcept the last row that I am getting looks like this: |E401494 | HONEYWELL / HON | 2016-04-18 | 2017-11-07. So i just have to replace last row's End_Date with Null that's it....right.?

Comment: Could be a data cleaning issue.

Comment: Can you elaborate that please.? What sort of issue it could be so that I can fix it the code itself that I have written.?

Comment: I don't have visibility on the data you are speaking about. The solution was based on the sample data you provided. In your original data, I suspect it could be a data formatting issue. And I do not think - it should be fixed in code.

Comment: Ooh okay...got it....let me try this solution on the complete dataset that I have. Will post a comment here once it's executed and validated. If anything else comes up will post that here as well.! Thanks a bunch.!

Comment: And accept and upvote if your problem was solved, so it might help others in finding the solution for a similar problem. Cheers!

Comment: sure will do.! Cheers.!

Comment: If you want to keep missing values (i.e. `NaT`), replace the `max` aggregator of the `"End_Date"` column by this lambda `lambda s: s.max(skipna=False)` that tells the series to not skip them.

Comment: @Kris can we use multiple columns in this code as I need to use EID columns as well:      
            df['groups'] = (df['CLEAN_NAME'].ne(df['CLEAN_NAME'].shift())).cumsum()

Comment: `df[['CLEAN_NAME','EID']]` should work

Comment: @Kris  Thanks will try it out.!

Comment: @alih Thanks will try it out.!

Comment: @Kris I am getting this error "Wrong number of items passed 2, placement implies 1" even when I use df[['CLEAN_NAME','EID']]. I need to use this at both places.?

Comment: @Kris     df['groups'] =(df[['CLEAN_NAME','EID']].ne(df[['CLEAN_NAME','EID']].shift())).cumsum()   I used this still got the error

Comment: @Kris got the solution.! I only had to change this:                                                              
                df = df.groupby(["groups","EID"]).agg({"CLEAN_NAME": "first", "Start_Date": min, "End_Date": max}).reset_index()